# Is it natural to say "fix a situation"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it natural to use *fix* in the following context?

> We are losing money because of poor management, so we had better **fix the situation** ASAP.

Would it be more natural to use *put right the situation* or *redeem the situation* in the context? If neither is natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: The object normally comes before the preposition in phrasal verb contexts like *put the situation right* (but that one's not particularly idiomatic anyway). In a relatively formal "management-speak" context, you'd more likely encounter ***address** the situation* (obviously with the strong implication that if we ***deal with it*** at all, we will do so ***successfully***).

Comment: What do you think about "redress the situation"? And what about "fix the situation"?

Comment: I probably wouldn't use ***redress*** there, no. It could work in certain contexts where it's obvious "the [current] situation" is a very temporary deviation from the ***normal*** situation (that you want to ***get back to***), but even then I'd say it would be a relatively unusual ("stylised") form. By contrast, although ***address*** was once a relatively "stylised, formal" usage, it's becoming increasingly common even in relaxed conversational contexts today. Still nowhere near as common as ***deal with it,*** though).

Comment: What about "fix the situation"? Do you think it is natural?

Comment: Fix is fine, if a bit American. I have heard Brits talk about 'mending' a situation or relationship, also 'repair'.

Comment: Per [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deal+with+the+situation%2Caddress+the+situation%2Cfix+the+situation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeal%20with%20the%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caddress%20the%20situation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfix%20the%20situation%3B%2Cc0) ***situations*** are usually ***dealt with*** or ***addressed***, with ***fixing*** being a fairly distant third choice. But this isn't a particularly important choice, since they're all "acceptable", and easily understood (as having equivalent meaning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite natural.

In fact, *to fix* is used a lot in a figurative way. The first example that comes to my mind is *Fix You*, by Coldplay:

> Lights will guide you home
>   And ignite your bones
>   And I will try to **fix** you

*I will try to fix you*= *I will try to make you happy, make your day better, etc.*

Comment: I wouldn't say that this use of ***fix*** is "figurative". The first definition for the verb form in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fix) ***to repair something***, which I'm sure most people would agree is a "literal" sense (allowing for the fact that "all language is metaphor").